# Dynamic Variable Properties

Tags: powershell

I'm generating a variable in a foreach loop that's name is dynamic and I need to set properties

```
$variableName = "res" + $i
New-Variable -Name $variableName -Value New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
```

And then I need to add the properties, but just using

```
$variableName.text = "ipsum"
```

Would set the property of $variableName and not the created variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use the `Get-Variable` cmdlet to do this with the `-ValueOnly` parameter so that you get the variable returned and not an object that contains properties about the variable:

```
(Get-Variable $variableName -ValueOnly).text = "ipsum"
```

Note there was also a bug in your code, in that:

```
New-Variable -Name $variableName -Value New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
```

Needs to be:

```
New-Variable -Name $variableName -Value (New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label)
```

**Screenshot:**

[image: Accessing a dynamically named variable with PowerShell]

Comment: Receiving this when doing so: "The property 'Text' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set."

Comment: When I tested it there was a bug in your code here: `New-Variable -Name $variableName -Value New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label` which needs to be this `New-Variable -Name $variableName -Value (New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label)`

Answer (score 1):

you can do it too

```
$listLabel=@{}

for ($i = 1; $i -lt 99; $i++)
{ 
   $listLabel[$i]+=New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
   $listLabel[$i].Name="Res$i" 
   $listLabel[$i].Text="Text for $i" 
}
```